# Dockerfile Находится в под папке , оттуда COPY не делается, выводит ошибку что находит composer.json файл

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose

В Laravel проекте Dockerfile  находится в папке `.docker/app`  использую docker-compose файл
получаю ошибку в консоле что не находит composer.json файл
в докер файле это строка

```
# Copy composer.json
COPY composer.json /var/www/
```

пробовал также использовать релатив путь

```
# Copy composer.json
COPY ../../composer.json /var/www/
```

получаю ту же самую ошибку, не находит этот файл, что делать ?

Comment: Нужен кусок из `docker-compose.yml` с этим контейнером.

Answer (score 2):

Вот это будет работать только если `composer.json` лежит в той же папке, что и `Dockerfile`

```
COPY composer.json /var/www/
```

А вот так не будет работать вообще никогда

```
COPY ../../composer.json /var/www/
```

потому что Докер принципиально поддерживает копирование только начиная с уровня, где лежит `Dockerfile` и подпапки. Выше - это было бы security flaw.

Comment: Не совсем так. Докер поддерживает копирования начиная с уровня контекста, который можно задать кастомно.

Comment: @zalex Разве `context:` - это не то место, где лежит `Dockerfile` ?

Comment: вы запросто можете указать контекст ../../../  а от него путь к Dockerfile в соответствующем параметре. Т.е. по сути контекст это корень , однако не обязательно чтоб в нем лежал Dockerfile .

Comment: Вот тут например. https://github.com/Kolbasyatin/learn-php-platform/blob/master/backend/.docker/docker-compose.yaml

Контекст родительская папка относительно docker-compose.  Dockerfile задан путём .